# ionic info shows ionic framework is unknown

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I would like run the ionic app in the browser.

I used this command

`ionic serve`

But I got this error `Error: spawn EACCES`

I check ionic info but I got ionic framework is unknown

```
global packages:

@ionic/cli-utils : 1.4.0
Cordova CLI      : 7.0.1 
Gulp CLI         : CLI version 3.9.1 Local version 3.9.1
Ionic CLI        : 3.4.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova : 1.4.1
Cordova Platforms         : android 6.4.0
Ionic Framework           : unknown
```

System:

```
Node       : v7.10.1
OS         : Linux 4.13
Xcode      : not installed
ios-deploy : not installed
ios-sim    : not installed
npm        : 4.2.0
```

Comment: did you provide full permission to Gradle for android build ?

Comment: @CodeChanger how to give permission

Answer (score 1):

You have to **reinstall ionic and cordova**. Run this command:

```
npm install -g ionic cordova
```

Answer (score 0):

Install ionic and Cordova globally by using these commands.

1 . sudo npm install -g ionic@latest.

2 . sudo npm install -g cordova@latest.

Comment: I developed ionic1 version

Answer (score 0):

Remove and install Ionic latest/stable Version and open the project in Android Studio and perform a successful gradle.

Once done with the above procedure run the following command on your terminal in case you are using a MAC:

> sudo chmod 777 "/Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-4.1/bin/gradle"

Answer (score 0):

Go to root folder of your ionic project and Follow the below instructions:

run `sudo cordova prepare`

run `sudo chmod -R 777 ./`

run `ionic serve`

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs for linux and mac system

1st add “read and write“ permission to the project folder

Right click on the project folder-> click on get info -> add permissions

Now use   “sudo” before all syntax

Like , sudo ionic cordova run android

Answer (score 0):

might you missing to add path in environment for C:\Users\username\AppData .otherwise you have install ionic CLI once again with respected node version

user name is respected  to your user name

Answer (score 0):

Install ionic and Cordova globally by using these commands.
To install the ionic cli:

`npm install -g ionic@latest`

To install  the cordova cli:

`npm install -g cordova@latest`

Then run:

`ionic serve`